# Ajax Extensions vs Ajax Control Toolkit

Tags: ajax

What is the relation between Ajax Extensions and Ajax Control Toolkit?

Why I am asking is My UpdatePanel, Control template was working good by rendering section of the page. After when I Installed Ajax Control Toolkit for vs 2012 to implement Ajax CalendarExtendar by doing ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager my Updatepanel , control template is not working. (ie) my whole page started rendering. Again If I remove ajax tools and Ajax.dll from reference my page is working good by rendering particially (ie) the section of the page is rendering for UpdatePanel, Control template.

So, What is the relation , what I have to do to make use of both.

Thanks in advance

rejoin2me